# Docker + Rails + NGINX - "wrong" IP-Address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx, networking, docker-compose

I have a setup consisting of a Rails-App, NGINX and Docker. I have to use the Client's IP-Address in the Rails-App. But I only get the IP-Address of a docker network bridge in the Rails-App.

How can I get the real IP Address of the client?

Comment: you can get the clients IP address in client-side Javascript, and then get this information submitted, or pushed in a cookie. but none of this is really related to nginx, docker or ruby ....

Comment: It is. I want to get the Client's IP-Address in the Network in which he is.

Comment: yes, but what you're asking for is the clients-ip address, which is at the client end, where docker, nginx, and the rest do not exist ... at the client end there is only the web browser.  there would be specific implementations about handling cookies, or handling the submission of data that would involve ROR, but the rest is essentially irrelevant in terms of tags. over-use of tags will often get your question downvoted.

Comment: Okay, I found the solution. Sorry for so many tags, I didn't know where the problem was. In the end I just updated Docker to the newest version and it worked.